# If Kim Jong Un and Donald Trump switched places, who would be happier?

Tags: society, politics, geopolitics

Followup question: if Kim Jong Un and Donald Trump switched *bodies* who would be happier?

Edit: I am trying to write a short story.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! We love hypothetical questions here. The thing is, this doesn't seem to be about worldbuilding much... Maybe you could expand on it?

Comment: this would be better in the writers Stack exchange if you are looking for writing help. http://writers.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a serious answer?

The immediate staff of both leaders would conclude that there has been some sort of mental breakdown. Their principal would have "forgotten" things as basic as the language they speak or the faces and names of their immediate staff.

In the United States, the Chief of Staff would probably inform the Vice President. They may or may not try to keep the lapse quiet in the hope that it was only temporary. Odds are that it would leak quickly.

In North Korea, things are more difficult. Their *dear supreme generalissimo for life* is not interchangeable, he needs the descent from grandpa to justify his rule and the people are probably not ready for a junta of generals or party functionaries. His sister is probably not ready to step in. There would be little information at first as the regime scrambles for a solution.

Neither one would be able to return to his "proper" country. A leader who has had a mental breakdown won't be allowed to defect.

Comment: The government would probably announce an assassination attempt and use it as justification to close down the borders (even further)....in both cases. The leader would be confined in close quarters during "convalescence" indefinitely

Comment: @nzaman, which government? Of course both sides would have their own reasons to uphold the *dignity* of their leader. For one side it is a question of pride, for the other it might be a question of literal life and death. Being too ill to appear in public isn't good.

Comment: ...Precisely :-D